# Loading elements one after another - simple jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some JavaScript that loads a stack of separate elements based on their class name. However, I'd like to add a 1second delay on each, so they all appear one after another.

So **i1** loads first then a second later **i2** loads and so on...

How do I achieve this with my code?

```
<script>
jQuery(function($){

var i1 = $(".one"),
i2 = $(".two"),
i3 = $(".three");
i4 = $(".four");
i5 = $(".five");
i6 = $(".six");

$('.field').animate( {
marginTop:"0"
},600, function () {
i1.animate({
"opacity": 1
}),             
i2.animate({
"opacity": 1
}),     
i3.animate({
"opacity": 1
}),     
i4.animate({
"opacity": 1
})      
i5.animate({
"opacity": 1
}),     
i6.animate({
    "opacity": 1
}, 500);
});             

});
</script>
```

Many thanks for any help with this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using jQuery .delay(), it allows you to delay the execution of functions that follow it in the queue.

http://api.jquery.com/delay/

**UPDATED:**

Working jsFiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/DylanNunns/su8jp/2/

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var i1 = $(".one"),
        i2 = $(".two"),
        i3 = $(".three");
    i4 = $(".four");
    i5 = $(".five");
    i6 = $(".six");

    $('.field').animate({
        marginTop: "0"
    }, 600, function () {
        i1.delay(1000).animate({
            "opacity": 1
        }),
        i2.delay(2000).animate({
            "opacity": 1
        }),
        i3.delay(3000).animate({
            "opacity": 1
        }),
        i4.delay(4000).animate({
            "opacity": 1
        }),
        i5.delay(5000).animate({
            "opacity": 1
        }),
        i6.delay(6000).animate({
            "opacity": 1
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I believe the Queue feature alone does the delay internally, does it no? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.queue/

Comment: Thanks, Dylan. Can you possibly show me how I would use this in my example above?

Comment: @michaelmcgurk Hey Michael, sorry for the wait. It's a little hackish but it shows it working. Hope this helps! http://jsfiddle.net/DylanNunns/su8jp/

Comment: I looooove hackish :-D Thanks so much for the reply and the demo, much clearer now. My parenthesis was whack.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this way:-

#### Html

```
<div class="one slide">1</div> <!-- give some common class all these-->
<div class="two slide">2</div>
<div class="three slide">3</div>
<div class="four slide">4</div>
<div class="five slide">5</div>
```

#### JS

```
var all = $('.slide').get(); //Get all the element to slide into an array.

function animate() {

    var elem = all.shift(); //Remove the top element from the array

   //animate it
    $(elem).animate({
        "opacity": 1
    }, function () {
        if (all.length > 0)
              window.setTimeout(animate, 1000); //set the time out after the delay of 1 sec for next element to animate.
    });
}
animate();
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/B66V8/)

Comment: I did not downvote, but all you solution does is **extend** the animation, it does not delay it as the OP is trying to do.

Comment: @Neal Thanks, i realized it after your comment. :)

Comment: This works, but it takes control away from jQuery. You can't cancel the animations using `.stop()` for example.

Comment: @iblamefish Don't understand why OP needs to stop the animation in this case. He just wants them to appear one after the other.

Answer (score 2):

For each element, set `animate` function inside the callback of animate method of the previous element.

```
$('.field').animate({
    marginTop: "0"
}, 600, function () {
    i1.animate({
        "opacity": 1
    }, function () {
        i2.animate({
            "opacity": 1
        },etc...);
```

Comment: Good answer, roasted. Could you possibly show me how I then close it - I'm getting errors and I'm sure it's my parenthesis :'( http://pastebin.com/X8RmT02W

Answer (score 2):

Without leaking variables and having to add a new `class`, you can loop through the found elements and use `setTimeout` to delay time until the next. For example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var i1 = $(".one"),
        i2 = $(".two"),
        i3 = $(".three"),
        i4 = $(".four"),
        i5 = $(".five"),
        i6 = $(".six"),
        iterator = function () {
            var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0),
                len = arr.length,
                iterate = function (index) {
                    if (index === len) {
                        return;
                    }
                    arr[index].animate({
                        opacity: 1
                    }, 600, function () {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            iterate(++index);
                        }, 1000);
                    });
                };
            iterate(0);
        };

    iterator(i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6);
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/FbGwQ/2/

Answer (score 0):

I like to use jQuery's `each` method along with `delay` to help out with this because it gives you the index of an element which you can use to set the delay.

```
jQuery(function () {
  var animation_items = [
        ".one", ".two", ".three", ".four", ".five", ".six"
      ];

  $.each(animation_items, function(index, item) {
    $(item).delay(index * 1000).animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

You also get the added bonus of it working with a specific class instead of specifying them all separately. This makes everything more general and easier to maintain. You can simply add another div to your HTML without having to edit the JavaScript.

```
<div class="fade_in"></div>
<div class="fade_in"></div>
<div class="fade_in"></div>


jQuery(function () {
  var delay = 1000;

  $('.fade_in').each(function(index, item) {
    $(item).delay(index * 1000).animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

Here's a [demo](http://jsbin.com/utezuc/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd rather use a bit of recursion and use the callbacks for a cleaner implementation (in my mind ..)

```
var oneByOne = function($el) {
    $el.fadeIn(600, function() {
        if (!$el.next().length == 0)
            oneByOne($el.next());
    });
};
$first = $('#one-by-one').children().first();
oneByOne($first);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mikecmpbll/sbwMx/

Alternatively, still using recursion but working with the array of items instead:

```
var oneByOne = function(arr) {
    $el = $(arr.shift());
    $el.fadeIn(600, function() {
        if (!$el.next().length == 0)
            oneByOne(arr);
    });
};
arr = $("#one-by-one").children().get();
oneByOne(arr);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mikecmpbll/sbwMx/1/